# Resultado #¡NÚM! en dos acciones del if

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, condiciones, null

A través de un formulario google entran los datos a una hoja de cálculo google. Son los pagos de cuotas de viviendas.  Pueden pagar Cuota Mensual(monto1), Cuota Especial(monto2) y, Cuota Mensual y Especial(monto3 y monto4).  Necesito que al ingresar los datos me sume las cantidades y como no se que pagarán sumaba totas las columnas donde entraban los resultados (13, 15,19 y 21) de la fila "row".  Pero lo que hacía era concatenar los números.  Me dí cuenta que eso ocurría debido a que quedaban celdas vacias porque no ingresaban datos en ellas debido a que la persona podía escoger qué iba a pagar, entonces hay veces entran datos al monto1, otras veces al monto2 y otras solamente al monto3 y monto4.  Debido a eso traté de usar el "if" para decidir si un monto era diferente a null tomar una acción.  Y traté de resolver así:

```
  var monto1 = hoja1.getRange(row,13).getValues();  
  var monto2 = hoja1.getRange(row,15).getValues();
  var monto3 = hoja1.getRange(row,19).getValues();
  var monto4 = hoja1.getRange(row,21).getValues();
   if (monto3 != null && monto4 != null){
       var m3 = parseInt(monto3); 
       var m4 = parseInt(monto4);
       var mt = m3 + m4;
       hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(mt);
  } else if (monto2 != null) {
               var m2 = parseInt(monto2);               
               hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(m2);
  } else {
    var m1 = parseInt(monto1);
    hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(m1);
  }
```

Me suma bien la primera parte: `var  mt = m3 + m4`  pero cuando evalua para monto2 y monto1 el resultado que da es:  #¡NÚM! y NO ENTIENDO POR QUÉ.  Espero haberme dado a entender y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: No está clara la pregunta. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con código que no funciona deben incluir información suficiente para reproducir el problema, que en el caso de las hojas de cálculo de Google deberían incluir, sin limitarse a esto, 1. Datos de entrada indicando , 2. Resultado esperado, 3.el enlace a una hoja de cálculo compartida con cualquiera que tenga el enlace para ver, 4. un [mcve] del código, es decir, una función completa con el mínimo de líneas necesarias parar para reproducir problema, no sólo un extracto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PARA LOS INTERESADOS.  Con parseInt no da el resultado esperado en mi caso debido que al tener un campo vacío da respuesta como NaN aquí:

```
if (monto3 != null && monto4 != null){
       var m3 = parseInt(monto3); 
       var m4 = parseInt(monto4);
       var mt = m3 + m4;
       hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(mt);
  } else if (monto2 != null) {
               var m2 = parseInt(monto2);               
               hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(m2);
  } else {
    var m1 = parseInt(monto1);
    hoja1.getRange(row,5).setValue(m1);
  }
```

Pero NO ES NECESARIO NI SIQUIERA EL USO DEL IF. con colocar Number en la captura del dato ya me convierte un dato vacio a cero: Así:

```
var monto1 = Number(hoja1.getRange(row,13).getValues());  
var monto2 = Number(hoja1.getRange(row,15).getValues());
var monto3 = Number(hoja1.getRange(row,19).getValues());
var monto4 = Number(hoja1.getRange(row,21).getValues());
```

De esta forma puedo sumar los montos sin importar si el dato de entrada fue dejado vacío o no porque el vacio lo convierte en cero.
var total = monto1 + monto2 + monto3 + monto4;  Y siempre tendre el total ingresado.
Espero les siva de algo.  Y gracias a los que quisieron ayudarme.